# No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, roscd, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am migrating from ROS Electric, to ROS Hydro.  I am struggling with Catkin.  I have my Catkin and Beginner_tutorials directories setup.  But when I type roscd beginner_tutorials, I get No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials.  I know that I probably do not have it sourced properly.  I have been around and around with the tutorials.  But still stuck.

Thank you,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143246/no-such-package/stack-%27beginner_tutorials/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-22**:
Have you source the setup.bash file in catkin/build (or devel I don't have my computer with me and I don't remember) ? I asked a similar question and I didn't source that one.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-03-24**:
I can roscd anything in my /opt/ros/hydro directory, but roscd will not find any ros directories in my home directory unless I source it.

Morpehus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have installed ROS hydro, sourced its setup file (`/opt/ros/hydro/setup.*sh`), the created a new workspace for the tutorials (as described in the wiki), and then run `catkin_make` at least once, you should be able to find a `setup.*sh` in the `devel` folder of your workspace.

If that doesnt help, can you describe how exactly you have your "Catkin and Beginner_tutorials directories setup"?

**Edit**

I suggest removing everything ROS related from your `.bashrc` and just place the line `source ~/ros_workspace/devel/setup.bash`. With this setup you have to be careful however. When you decide to create another workspace in the future, it will overlay `~/ros_workspace` and not `/opt/ros/hydro/` if you do not manually source `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` manually before the first call to `catkin_make` in your new workspace.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-03-23**:
It maybe how my bash.rc is configured. Here is the last part of my bash.rc file:
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}

#export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
#export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
#export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-23**:
With catkin you shouldn't manually set ROS_WORKSPACE or ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Just source the setup.bash of the devel space of your workspace (`source ~/ros_workspace/devel/setup.bash`)

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-03-23**:
Are you saying that I need to comment out ROS_WORKSPACE & ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in my bash.rc file?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-28**:
In hydro, working only with catkin packages, there is usually no need to set any of these environment variables manually. If you have set up your workspace correctly, you need to only source one setup.*sh file, namely the one from your devel or install space of that workspace.